# what is *.do in struts-config.xml

Tags: java, servlets, struts

I am learing struts and I found a mapping in Struts-config.xml as follow

```
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```

in servlet mapping tag.

what is *.do

Can we achive the same in web.xml of servlets ?

Thanks in Advance ,

Raj

Comment: That's in web.xml, not a Struts config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*.do` - It just means that any URL that ends with a ".do"
 Yes we can achive the same in web.xml of servlets 
ie: any url requests that ends with `.do` will be redirected to the specified Servlet  , In our case to the servlet named `action`

[This Link](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/39833) give you a good idea about **web.xml** and **struts-config.xml** and **difference** between them

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know .do url invokes your servlet. I have seen this extension being used with Struts.

So if you have www.hey.com/hello.do 
Then you struts configuration will have something as follows

```
<struts-config>
    <action-mappings>
        <action path="/hello" type="com.MyAction">
    </action-mappings>
</struts-config>
```

So in this example the url"www.hey.com/hello.do" will be forwarded to MyAction.java

In your particular example, you found that occurrence of *.do in your web.xml file. What that means is all request that ends with *.do will be forwarded to "action" servlet.

Answer (score 1):

Every url which ends with *.do it calls your servlet.